How prefetching instructions achieve latency hiding？
Here is an example of manually adding prefetch instructions(to CPU cache) to accelerate binary search：
using prefetch to accelerate binary search
By prefetching the location for the next binary search, the author's experiments show an approximate 14% performance speedup.
I would like to ask how instruction prefetching achieves acceleration. If instruction prefetching cannot be parallelized with other instructions, then it merely brings the memory read latency forward, which, in principle, wouldn’t lead to performance improvement.
So, it can be inferred that instruction prefetching should be able to run in parallel with commonly used computational instructions. What is the principle of this parallelism? Taking the example of a prefetch followed by a series of ADD instructions, I suspect that prefetching occupies certain memory components of the CPU, while the ADD instructions do not require memory bandwidth, allowing both to run in parallel. I would like to obtain some resources to study this topic further.
I am trying to understand how CPU instruction prefetching can lead to performance improvement, but I don’t know the reasons behind this performance gain.

Yes, it is done in the background. I would compare binary search to dividing the current internal in more than two halfs per step. E.g. three or four parts and profiling, before deciding that binary with prefetch is the fastest option.

Memory-level parallelism is a thing.  Skylake from 2015 for example can have about 12 cache misses or prefetches outstanding (12 LFBs = Line Fill Buffers for L1 misses, 16 superqueue entries for L2 misses.)  See https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ re: instruction-level parallelism.

For binary search, you'd want data prefetching with software-prefetch instructions.  It looks like that's what you're talking about.  But "instruction prefetching" implies prefetch into L1i cache.  "prefetch instructions" is the term you want to describe instructions that tell the CPU which cache line to prefetch, for cases where the hardware prefetch units can't predict.

Maybe a duplicate of Parallel memory access on modern processors .  Binary search mostly isn't limited by bandwidth, it's limited by latency.  Also Prefetching Examples? has perf stat measurements from a bsearch with prefetch.
